# Flink docker container job persistance

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-flink, persistent-storage

I am trying to deploy a flink cluster with docker compose, this has been working fine, but whenever the job manager is restarted it drops all of the JAR files.

According to the flink website: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/docker.html

I need to mount the folder location like this:  - /host/path/to/job/artifacts:/opt/flink/usrlib

however, upon successfully doing so, no jobs appear to be available within the management interface. I can enter into the container and see the mount has worked successfully

Is this the wrong location ? Or is there something else im missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. Yet I believe in a production setup, it would make sense to store the jars in some kind of software repository (e.g. artifactory). Then you could start jobs from a deployment pipeline such as Jenkins or Github actions. As part of the deployment pipeline, you could upload the jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your jobs to recover from a job manager restart, you'll need to configure [high availability](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html).

Comment: For this particular situation, the deployment is on the edge, so the instance of the job manager going down is the result of the entire system being restarted and a high availability set up isn’t really an option

My only main concern is that the job manager “loses” all the jar files and they have to be reloaded via the web interface which is a bit of a nightmare. 

The only requirement here is for the job manager container to persist the storage of those jar files

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#advanced-options-for-flink-web-ui)
You have to set the upload path `web.upload.dir` or Flink will create a dynamic directory under `web.tmpdir` `/tmp` by default, then you can mount the upload directory to a Volume.
Ex:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.13.0-scala_2.11
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        web.upload.dir: /opt/flink/flink-web
    volumes:
      - ./data/flink-web:/opt/flink/flink-web
      - ./data/usrlib:/opt/flink/usrlib
  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.13.0-scala_2.11
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    scale: 1
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 5
    volumes:
      - ./data/usrlib:/opt/flink/usrlib
```